# Apply custom R function across datafrmae to produce new column

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have wrote a custom function in R which has two date variable inputs. I have 2 columns of dates in my dataframe and I want to apply the custom function to the 2 dates on each row of the dataframe to produce a new mutated column in the dataframe giving the result of

I think this would involve using mutate / across but I can't work out how. Can anyone help me amend the below for it to work please?

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate(new_column = dplyr::across(c(date_column_1, date_column_2), custom_function))
```

Comment: Most R functions are already "vectorized", in that you can call `df <- mutate(df, z = f(x, y))`, or without dplyr `df$z <- f(df$x, df$y)`. You might be overthinking this. If you can post the actual function you are using (or at least explain what it does), it will be easier to help.

Comment: Note that `across` does not do what you seem to think it does. `across` applies _the same function_ to several columns independently, so `select(df, f(x), f(y), f(z))` is the same as `select(df, across(c(x, y, z), f))`. Eg [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html#ref-examples): `iris %>%
  mutate(across(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), round))`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `new_column` as the result of your function:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    new_column = custom_function(date_column_1, date_column_2)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. I had assumed that this would work originally, however I get the following error: ```Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `working_days_available = UK_working_days(attendance_start_date,
  attendance_end_date)`.
Caused by error in `seq.Date()`:
! 'from' must be of length 1```

Comment: NB the custom_function is working_days_available, date_column_1 is attendance_start_date and date_column_2 is attendance_end_date and 'from' which is causing the error is the first of the two variable inputs to the function, i.e. attendance_start_date

Comment: You will have to match the parameters to your function - it's possible your function requires `UK_working_days(c(attendance_start_date, attendance_end_date))`. I can be of more help if you share the code for your custom function

Comment: Sure, here is the code for the function.

Comment: ```UK_working_days <- function(from, to) {
  
  from <- lubridate::as_date(from)
  to <- lubridate::as_date(to)
  
  if (is.na(from) | is.na(to)) {
    warning("Warning: a date missing")
    return(NA)
  } else if (from > to) {
    warning("Warning: 'To' date is before From date")
    return(NA)
  } else if (from == to) {
    warning("Warning: 'From' date same as 'To' date")
    return(0)
  }
  
  x <- base::seq(from, to, by = 1)
  x <- x[lubridate::wday(x, week_start = 1) <= 5]
  x <- base::setdiff(x,holidays)
  length(x)
}```